# create a new column contains ISO week postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have table like this:

| CustomerID | Trans_date |
| --- | --- |
| C001 | 01-sep-22 |
| C001 | 04-sep-22 |
| C001 | 14-sep-22 |
| C002 | 03-sep-22 |
| C002 | 01-sep-22 |
| C002 | 18-sep-22 |
| C002 | 20-sep-22 |
| C003 | 02-sep-22 |
| C003 | 28-sep-22 |
| C004 | 08-sep-22 |
| C004 | 18-sep-22 |

I would make a new column consist ISO week

| CustomerID | Trans_date | Week_ISO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | 01-sep-22 | 35 |
| C001 | 04-sep-22 | 35 |
| C001 | 14-sep-22 | 35 |
| C002 | 03-sep-22 | 35 |
| C002 | 01-sep-22 | 35 |
| C002 | 18-sep-22 | 35 |
| C002 | 20-sep-22 | 35 |
| C003 | 02-sep-22 | 35 |
| C003 | 28-sep-22 | 35 |
| C004 | 08-sep-22 | 36 |
| C004 | 18-sep-22 | 36 |

But i can't make because there's not have `datepart`

Comment: Please note that `datepart` is not supported in Postgresql.

Comment: aaaa that's why i got error

Comment: @Stefanov.sm i still trying but i dont know how to solve the query

Comment: Fine, see my answer

Comment: Using an ISO week _without_ the corresponding ISO year almost never makes sense

Comment: But why add a new column that duplicates data that can easily and efficiently be extracted from the existing value? If you don't want to type it every time, use a VIEW

Answer (score 1):

You can define a view instead of altering the original table. Use [extract or date_part](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

```sql
create or replace view the_view as
select customerid, trans_date, 
       extract('week' from trans_date) week_iso
from the_table;
```

[DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/81aqm6tVYbZAgpQFw1A2z3/0)

Comment: the Query returned successfully, but the table isn't updating...

Comment: @cillawclarss: Check the view, that's where you can see the result. This doesn't update the table, doesn't store the result, just shows you the result when you need it. But you could also do an update on your table, at the cost of extra storage needed

Comment: Of course not. This is a definition of a view. You may write an update statement using the `extract` expression and then the table will update.

Comment: but it doesn't display any result either, it only gets a message if the query's successful

Comment: Run `select * from the_view`. Have a look at the fiddle.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm sorry...but to save the result of that query, how do you do it?

Comment: Better do not but use the view instead of the table